# Why does Spark UI shows only Actions in the DAG under Jobs Tab and no Transformations

Tags: user-interface, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple program -

```
lines =sc.parallelize(['a','b','c','d'])
lines.map(myfunct1).flatMap(flatmapfunc).map(myfunct2).collect()
```

When I submit this program in Spark and view the DAG under the Jobs tab I am able to see only parallelize and collect actions but not map and flatmap.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLOKm.png)

Any thoughts on why I am not able to see any transformations in the DAG?

Answer (score 0):

Spark UI doesn't support Python `RDD`s very well. You can use Python `DataFrame`s instead.